# Eclipse class not found

Tags: java, android, eclipse

just messed up with changing the package name in eclipse as I created a new name for the application package for a android app. Now struck with class not found exception..Have already renamed in.xml file and moved the classes to the default package.

The error is

```
04-21 14:35:00.386: E/AndroidRuntime(3735): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 14:35:00.386: E/AndroidRuntime(3735): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{in.silverspoon.locationnearby/in.silverspoon.locationnearby.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "in.silverspoon.locationnearby.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/in.silverspoon.locationnearby-3.apk
```

Any help in the right direction would be great.

Comment: post the manifest and packagename in your MainActivity

Comment: check in your build section, whether you selected your third party libraries in export section, Class not found exception usually cause due to missing of class files

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application's manifest declares an activity that doesn't exist. Make sure that the declaration coincides with the activity's fully qualified name.

You can read more about the manifest [in this API guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).